# Overlapped Distplot Seaborn [fill]

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create an overlapped distplot in which the densities are handled separately.

```
g = sns.displot(
data=df,
x="continuous_variable",
hue="categorical_variable",
kind="kde",
fill=True,
palette=sns.color_palette("bright")[:2],
height=5,
aspect=1.5,
legend=False)
```

To which I get an [distplot with overlapped probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIgZF.png)  <- click to see the picture

I personally don't like this graph and would like to get 2 dist plots separately as follows:

```
data1 = df[df['categorical_variable'] == 1]
data2 = df[df['categorical_variable'] == 0]

sns.distplot(data1[['continuous_variable']], hist=False, color = 'red')
sns.distplot(data2[['continuous_variable']], hist=False, color = 'blue')
```

To which I get 2 separate [distplots in the same graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JAPb.png)  <- click to see the picture.

I want to add a "fill" to these plots however from the above code. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You are mixing the names `displot` (a new figure-level function) and `distplot` (an old, deprecated function). Is that on purpose?  Note that `sns.displot` (and the axes-level `sns.kdeplot`) have a parameter `common_norm=False` (if you want the sizes independent of the number of values belonging to each hue). You can do `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12,10))` with `sns.kdeplot(x=data1[['continuous_variable']], color='red', fill=True, ax=ax1)` to get separate subplots.

Comment: Or `g = sns.displot(data=df, x="continuous_variable", col="categorical_variable", kind="kde", fill=True, palette="bright", height=5, aspect=1.5, legend=False)` to automatically create two subplots.  Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72351219/edit) your post and explain with a bit more detail what exactly you want to achieve.